# Qt - several QTextBlock inline

Tags: qt, qtextdocument

Is it possible to arrange several QTextBlocks in QTextDocument in one horizontal line?

I need to know which block of text was clicked and QTextBlock would be nice to use due to its method setUserState(int), which can be used to hold id of particular block. Are there better approaches?

Comment: I have the exact same requirement as you. But it seems impossible. Especially since it's not possible to extend QTextBlock or any other Qt class involved in the process. Did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your question right, but I am taking a shot at it (some three years after the question was asked.....)

In principle you can put `QTextBlocks` in a horizontal line using a `QTextTable`. If you then create a class which inherits from `QTextEdit` you can catch the mouse events and find out which text block was clicked.

I post some code below where I have a very simply dialog that only has a textedit in it (of the derived class mentioned above). I create a table laying out three text blocks in a horizontal line and set their user state to the column number. Then I have the text edit class only with the overloaded `mouseEvent` method which only prints the `userState` of whatever text block it is in to the command line, just to show the principle.

Let me know if this is of any help or if misunderstood your question.

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include "ui_dialog.h"

class MyDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::Dialog
{
 public:
  MyDialog(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0);
  void createTable();

};


#endif
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QTextTable>
#include <QTextTableFormat>

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :
QDialog(parent,f)
{
  setupUi(this);
}

void MyDialog::createTable()
{
  QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();

  QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
  tableFormat.setCellPadding(40);
  tableFormat.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_None);

  QTextTable* table=cursor.insertTable(1,3,tableFormat);
  for( int col = 0; col < table->columns(); ++col ) {
    cursor = table->cellAt(0, col).firstCursorPosition();
    cursor.insertBlock();
    cursor.block().setUserState(col);
    cursor.insertText(QString("Block in Column ")+QString::number(col));
  }

}
```

**mytextedit.h**

```
#ifndef MYTEXTEDIT_H
#define MYTEXTEDIT_H

#include <QTextEdit>

class MyTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
 public:
  MyTextEdit(QWidget * parent = 0);
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
#endif
```

**mytextedit.cpp**

```
#include "mytextedit.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QtCore>

MyTextEdit::MyTextEdit(QWidget * parent) :
  QTextEdit(parent)
{

}

void MyTextEdit::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    qDebug() << this->cursorForPosition(event->pos()).block().userState();
  }
}
```

**main.cpp** (just for completeness)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc,argv);
  MyDialog dialog;

  dialog.show();
  dialog.createTable();

  return app.exec();

}
```

Comment: @Dejwi, is this answer of any help or is there any aspect that I got wrong in my answer?