# extend the definition of a block in a QTextDocument

Tags: c++, qt, block, qtextdocument

As far as I know ([official source](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext-structure.html)), Qt defines a *block* in a QTextDocument as a bunch of characters followed by **\n** or a similar character. Hence...

```
QTextDocument* doc = my_qtextedit.document();
QTextCursor cur = QTextCursor(doc);

cur.insertText("aaa\nbbb");

qDebug() << "nbr of blocks" << doc->blockCount();
```

... prints **"nbr of blocks=2"**.

But I need to

- (1) divide my text into several parts, arbitrary demarcated. By
  example, I need to be able to split the sentence "I'm twenty" into
  four blocks : "I", "'", "m" and "twenty".
- (2) easily access and modify these parts (and display them in a QTextEdit object).

The current *block* mechanism is interesting thanks to the find(), begin(), ... functions/iterators but I can't see how to specialize it to fit my requirements.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

**update** : [alas, it seems difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041341/qt-several-qtextblock-inline).

**update** : [QTextFragment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextfragment.html#text) only allows to modify the format of the text.